# Not able to run atlassian/gajira-cli@v3 on github actions

Tags: github-actions, jira

I'm trying to run gajira-cli to update/ comment on specific ticket on Jira using Github actions with following command:

```
jira edit [TICKET-ID] --noedit --comment="string"
```

However, it throws EOF error. What did I miss in the command I use?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Jira Cloud or Jira Server(hosted)?

Comment: I'm using Jira cloud